# Keywords in Action triggering unexpected exit and global response from Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

Certain keywords are exiting my action.

First of all, I'm aware that there are built-in/system intents ([docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/intents#list_of_intents)). I know that there are conversation exit keywords that trigger actions.intent.CANCEL and exit the action/conversation (eg. "exit", "cancel", "stop". See [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/conversation-exits)).

However, I cannot find any documentation referencing the keywords that are exiting my action (and any new one I create).

Keywords like "thank you", "help", "call center", consistently exit my action and submit the user query globally to Google Assistant. For example, inputting "thank you" during a conversation in my action will exit (ie. " has left the conversation") and Google Assistant will answer me with something like "That's what I was built for!". Testing in the simulator shows this exit as an invocation error (See [screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C0HC.png)), testing with Google Assistant on mobile shows the exit from action and answer from GA (See [screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf3Ea.png)).

Why is this happening instead of a fallback intent?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a case of [no-match yielding](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/intents#no-match_yielding) where some queries that does not match your Action will be executed by the Assistant instead.

If you do want to handle these queries yourself, you can add an intent that matches [freeform text](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/types#custom_types). Though this may come at a detriment to the user experience if they did intend for the Assistant to answer.