# conversation getting terminated when typing particular inputs

Tags: actions-on-google

we have a skill name abc . so when user types "podcast from channel xyz" it's existing the skill and taking us to google podcast how to stop it and continue inside the skill . I think google platforms also provide the podcast for channel xyz ..

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66675892/keywords-in-action-triggering-unexpected-exit-and-global-response-from-google-as

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keywords in Action triggering unexpected exit and global response from Google Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66675892/keywords-in-action-triggering-unexpected-exit-and-global-response-from-google-as)